# Navigating two times from landscape to portrait

Tags: navigation, uinavigationcontroller, landscape, landscape-portrait, portrait

While a button from landscape other is screen is locked to Portrait in iOS above version 17 OS its coming as two times and lower versions like iOS 15 0r 16 in that its working fine. What will be issue for that and please let me know if can be solved.